# How do I create a menu in Haskell for my application

Tags: haskell, menu

I am currently creating an application in haskell which allows the user to add an entry, remove an entry and view the information that is in a text file. What I would like to know is how to create a menu so that when the application is run a menu like this comes up:

```
Main Menu
1) Add Entry
2) Remove Entry
3) View all information
```

Once the user has selected a number between 1-3 it will execute the add, remove or view function and then loop back to the menu. Currently when I run the application I can add a new user and then it displays the new user in the file. This is because the code has not been split into separate functions and therefore executes it in one go.

Comment: Hi @dave4420 thank you for showing me the other thread. I have however encountered some problems. In the thread there are two examples, when I use the first example I get an error "parse error on input 'menu' and when I use the second example I get an error "Couldn't match expected type '[Char]' with actual data type 'IO ()' in the return type of a call of 'hPutStrLn'. Note: This is with me only using the code shown in the examples, I have not added any of the code I have written yet.

Comment: Both code examples compile fine for me. Are you sure you are copying the code exactly as shown? e.g. that you are copying+pasting, that the indentation (especially of the first line) isn't getting screwed up, that there is literally nothing else in the file you save to.

Comment: Hi @dave4420 the code is now compiling correctly, even though the copy + paste version looks exactly the same as the code I had typed in myself. For add entry I have used a putStrLn to ask a question, getLine to obtain the answer and appendFile to add the information to the text file. How can I make this code a function, would I have to use a let command? For example: let addEntry = putStrLn "Enter Username: " addUserName <- getLine appendFile "UserList.txt" (++ addUserName). Thanks for your help dave.

Comment: I think it's best if you post a new top-level question. Include a link to the other thread and make sure people know what code you're trying to modify. Also make sure you say what you've tried.